# Can sitemap XML files be outside of root directory

Tags: search-engine, sitemap

Can sitemap XML files be outside of root directory? I can't put the file into the Root of the website. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Please share if you have.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

> The location of a Sitemap file determines the set of URLs that can be included in that Sitemap. A Sitemap file located at http://example.com/catalog/sitemap.xml can include any URLs starting with http://example.com/catalog/ but can not include URLs starting with http://example.com/images/.

So the short answer is - yes, it can be located outside of the root directory, but it will only consider paths starting from the subdirectory level up as valid. Which is not something most people want.